# How do I access certain entity associated files from another portal in 2sxc module?

Tags: dotnetnuke, 2sxc

I want to access multiple files from single field of certain entity, which is at different portal. The problem is that when I try to use [this example](https://2sxc.org/en/blog/post/using-app-data-outside-of-2sxc-in-razor-custom-webapi-skin-or-another-module-300) or [this one](https://2sxc.org/en/docs/feature/feature/2684), its field of type `Hyperlink` contains empty string and method `AsAdam(entityObj, "FieldWithFiles").Files as IEnumerable<dynamic>` returns empty `IEnumerable<dynamic>`.
So is there a way to get files data from another portal in module 2sxc?

Environment used:
DNN v.9.6.1
2sxc v.11.5.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may fix itself in v11.11, but the general method is as follows:

Get the real file id (instead of the url) by accessing the raw APIs first - kind of like this

```
var entity = AsEntity(Content);
var realLink = entity.GetBestValue<string>("FieldNameWhichHasTheLink");

// now you have something like file:74 in realLink
// now continue with the DNN API to figure out what file 74 is, and if the permissions allow access
```

Comment: It didn't work in my case. Guess it's because field is of type Hyperlink (Library of files). How can I access library of files?

Comment: That's a tricky one - it probably does the folder lookup using the wrong portal. Basically you probably get an `AsAdam()` folder which points to the wrong portal root. Pls open an issue. As an un-sexy workaround I guess you would check what folder is returned on the AsAdam and then use normal file-io with the correct folder and check what files are there etc.

Comment: Is it supposed to return a set of file ids? From [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54823301/7402089) answer I thought there's just folder info and that's it.

Comment: That's correct - in Library-mode it just returns a folder. But you can ask it the folder name, - which will be wrong as it's pointing to the current portal - and then replace the root part like /portals/4/ with portals/2/ or whatever to then use System.IO to read the folder etc. Not perfect, but a temporary workaround till it does what it should.